# Convert a list of things into a list of sublists

Tags: list, function, haskell, stack

I want to write a function that converts a list of things into a list of sublists, each containing elements of the same value, which when concatenated together give the same list.

So `runs [1,2,2,1,3,3,3,2,2,1,1,4]` becomes `[[1],[2,2],[1],[3,3,3],[2,2],[1,1],[4]]`

How do I solve this problem in Haskell?

Comment: Take a look at [**`group`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:group).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This function already exists, this is [**`group :: Eq a => [a] -> [[a]]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:group):

```
Prelude> import Data.List(group)
Prelude Data.List> group [1,2,2,1,3,3,3,2,2,1,1,4]
[[1],[2,2],[1],[3,3,3],[2,2],[1,1],[4]]
```

Comment: That was awfully easy. Thank you very much

Answer (score 5):

It is often fruitful to check Hoogle when you're looking for a function that might already exist. Because you can search by type, you don't have to know what the function is called. And even if it doesn't exist, it's a good exercise because it makes you think about what type it should have.

Here, the simple type to start with is `[a] -> [[a]]`, but this search [yields no results](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=%5Ba%5D+-%3E+%5B%5Ba%5D%5D&scope=set%3Astackage). On reflection this makes sense: you can't split a list of arbitrary objects without some way to compare them.

There are a few ways you might think of to compare list items. One obvious one, since you want to group items that are equal, is Eq. So you might try a search for `Eq a => [a] -> [[a]]`, and this in fact yields [`group`](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=Eq+a+%3D%3E+%5Ba%5D+-%3E+%5B%5Ba%5D%5D&scope=set%3Astackage). You might similarly try `Ord a` instead, since Ord is another way to compare things, but this yields no results.

Lastly you might try the most general thing possible: take in a predicate function dictating where to split the list. A search for `(a -> a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [[a]]` yields [`groupBy`](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=%28a+-%3E+a+-%3E+Bool%29+-%3E+%5Ba%5D+-%3E+%5B%5Ba%5D%5D&scope=set%3Astackage), which is another reasonable way of achieving your goal, though in fact more general than necessary.